# Problem to extract the last column of each row in a table with selenium webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, extract

Hello I am trting to extract the last column(named B's) of the table at this webpage : https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/basketball/20200908/

Here is my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/basketball/20200908/")

nb_bookies = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(@class, 'center info-value')]")))]

print(nb_bookies)

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Here is the output :

```
['12', '9', '8', '1', '8', '12']
```

It is not what we have in the webpage.

Comment: I ran your code and its printing exactly same as present in table last column B. Let me know which value you are expecting and what is coming.

Comment: In the table we have [35 6 5 27 24 5 11 9 3 27 13 2 34]

Comment: With my code I have this : ['11', '3', '3', '8', '9', '3', '3', '4', '2', '10', '3', '2', '11']